# asp.net web api does not reach controller after basic authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, postman

I'm new in api and very much confused,I have implemented a basic authentication,it authenticate the user and I get 200 status, but then why it does not reach my controller?

my web api config:

```
       config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute());
       // config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());      
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


        // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
        // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
        // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
        //config.EnableQuerySupport();

        // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
        // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api

        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
```

my controller:

```
  [BasicAuthentication]

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id, string dttimeFrom, string dttimeTo)
    {          
        var _context = new TenMinutesContext();

        var rslt = (from m in _context.users

                     // where m.m_turbine_id == id 
                     select new User

                     {
                         m_user_name = m.m_user_name
                         // m.m_voltage_u12=
                     }).Take(10).ToList();
          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
                   rslt);
```

in postman I put http://localhost:51154/api/values?id=192.168.39.82&dttimeFrom=05102019&dttimeTo=10102019

and I get the user is authenticated,but why I cant see the controller result?

my BasicAuthentication Class:

```
    public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute: AuthorizationFilterAttribute
   {
  public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
     var authHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;

     if (authHeader != null)
     {
        var authenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
        var decodedAuthenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationToken));
        var usernamePasswordArray = decodedAuthenticationToken.Split(':');
        var userName = usernamePasswordArray[0];
        var password = usernamePasswordArray[1];

        // Replace this with your own system of security / means of validating credentials
        var isValid = userName == "rene" && password == "2019";

        if (isValid)
        {
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName), null);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

            actionContext.Response =
               actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
                  "User " + userName + " successfully authenticated");

            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext); 
        }
        else
        {
            HandleUnathorized(actionContext); 
        }
     }


  }

  private static void HandleUnathorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
     actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
     actionContext.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic Scheme='Data' location = 'http://localhost:");
  }

}
```

}

Comment: Are your controller action breakpoints being hit?

Comment: @mxmissile not actually it goes to the basic authentication class and returns me the authentication is successful ,and then will not return to my controller

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with `Web Api`, but I see your creating 2 Responses. I'm not sure you can return both of them. Try removing the one in your `OnAuthorization` method, see if your controller then get's hit.

Comment: @mxmissile then where should i validate the user?

Comment: Remove 2 lines `actionContext.Respose` and `base.OnAuthorization(actionContext)` and should work. You don't need to set Response on successful validation just let the user through. Only set response for invalid auth.